# Fastest way to get all combinations of numbers in array without gaps

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I need to calculate the sum from every possible combination of numbers in array (separate sums, not one total). Combinations cannot skip a number, so:

For y > x you need to add every number between a[x] and a[y].

For n-sized array you have (n)+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 , so for n = 5 there is 15 combinations.

I need to do as fast as possible and space is not a problem.

Edit: I tried:

```
unsigned long long r_all = 0;
std::vector<int> g_seentimes(m);

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    r_all += w[z];
    if(r_all > r){
        r = r_all;
    }
}

for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){

    unsigned long long r_temp = r_all;

    for(int i = 0; i<(n-j); i++){

        r_temp -= w[n-i];

        if( r_temp > r){
            r = r_temp;
        }
    }

    r_all -= w[y];

    if( r_all > r){
            r = r_all;
    }

}
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    unsigned long long r_temp = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<(n-i); j++){
        r_temp += w[i+j];
        if(r_temp > r){
            r = r_temp;
        }
    }
}
//r is the answer
```

Edit 2:
Expected output is maximum possible number, BUT example i privided is simplyfied version, originally if there is two or more of same number in combination, you dont add value of any of them, so {5, 3, 5, 3, 1} = 1, but {5, 3, 1} = 9. I got that part figured out, just need the fastest possible way to get through all combinations.

Edit 3:
[@Tuan333](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3713927/tuan333) Asked about number of combinations and i think it'll be easier to show it:

```
X- chosen, x-unchosen
n = 5

XXXXX    XXXXx    XXXxx    XXxxx    Xxxxx
xXXXX    xXXXx    xXXxx    xXxxx
xxXXX    xxXXx    xxXxx
xxxXX    xxxXx
xxxxX
```

Comment: 2 nested `for` loops. the 1st one selecting the size of the combination, and the second one inside adding the numbers..?

Comment: You need to show what you tried.

Comment: Can you provide an minor example of the expected output. I gave you a +1 for editing your question. :)

Comment: When you say every possible combinations of numbers, then for n numbers,there should be 2^n combinations, not n*(n+1)/2 combinations (hence if n = 5, there should be 2^5, not 15 combinations). Given a set of n numbers, there are n*(n+1)/2 ways to CHOOSE A SET OF TWO NUMBERS from the original set of n numbers. Which one are you after? Sums of any combinations of numbers or sum of any 2 numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make an array of the cumulative partial sums.  So if your numbers are `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` then that array would be `b = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]`.  (Note that I included the empty sum at the beginning so the second array is one larger.

Now observe, the sum of the `i`th through `j`th elements of `a` is `b[j+1] - b[i]`.  So now you can just do a double loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as `@btilly` 's solution, but here's an intuitive way to generate all sequences that you need:

```
X- chosen, x-unchosen
n = 5

Xxxxx
xXxxx
xxXxx
xxxXx
xxxxX

XXxxx
xXXxx
xxXXx
xxxXX

XXXxx
xXXXx
xxXXX

XXXXx
xXXXX

XXXXX
```

For each "block", you keep track of number of numbers that will be in your subsequences (let's call it blockLength). Then you only need to iterate through your original array to get the required subsequences, note that if your current subsequence has length blockLength, then you need to terminate at around (original array length - blockLength)th item. Here's the code (Java) to generate all subsequences. If there are repetitive numbers, you could remove them all through preprocessing.

```
int[] a = {5,3,1};
for(int subSeqLength = 1; subSeqLength <= a.length; subSeqLength++){
    for(int j = 0; j + subSeqLength <= a.length; j++){
        for(int k = j; k <j+subSeqLength; k++)
            System.out.print(a[k]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```